# Compass smart sprite layouts

Tags: sass, css-sprites, compass-sass

According to documentation http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/sprite-layouts/
There is a way to create 'smart' sprite layout, because I'm not satisfied with vertical one.

hello.sass

```
@orange-layout:smart
@import "orange/*.png"
@include all-orange-sprites
```

I'll try to generate it by command `compass compile test`

But it doesn't work for me. I'm still receiving 'vertical' sprite.

Comment: You have confirmation in console that the sprite is indeed regenerated ?

Comment: Sprite really generates.

Comment: FIXED:
Problem was in using @ instead of $.
Working version `$orange-layout:smart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in using @ instead of $. Working version $orange-layout:smart